# Splash screen still displayed although I removed the Default.png

Tags: ios

I don't want any more the splash screen, I have removed the Default.png from the resources file, also I have removed the sleep function.  However, when I run the app, the splash screen is still there, can you help me to figure out why it still displayed? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Deinstall the app! Or got to the Application folder and delete it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you clean the targets after you removed the image?  Xcode sometimes requires a clean between builds in order to notice changes to your images.  And if that does not work, uninstall the app from the simulator and rebuild.

Comment: Hi, how can i clean targets please, can you show me steps ? thx

Comment: In the build menu, select "Clean" or "Clean all Targets" depending on your Xcode version

Comment: i did the clean all targets stuff, now when i build and run, the Default is shown for a split second, is that normal, or the that's mean that the Default.png is still there (although i have deleted it) ? thx in advance :)

Comment: Then you probably need to delete the app from the simulator and reinstall

Comment: OMG, and how is that, shall i keep a copy first ?

Comment: No, don't delete the code itself, just open the simulator, tap and hold on the app's icon, hit the little X, then rebuild the app in Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the targets (Cmd+Shift+K), and if this doesn't work try to delete the app from the simulator/device and to reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

iOS always displays a "splash screen", AKA launch screen. When you don't provide an image, it initially shows a black screen. When the quits the app, iOS takes a screenshot just after your code return the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` and uses it as the new launch image (as long as your app doesn't quit).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and none of the cleaning activities nor uninstalling the app from simulator helped.

From my point of view there was a bug in xcode 3.x which is now properly fixed in V. 4.x